# Git add not working for modified, tracked files. No submodule, no .gitignore

Tags: git

I'm a new user of Git and I've searched to resolve this issue but no solutions have worked.

I've modified some files in a directory that is being tracked (checked using `git ls-remote`). When trying to add and commit, nothing is happening. I've tried:

`git add <dir>` then `git status`, but it just reports that there are untracked files (not the directory I want to add, but those I don't): `nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)`.

The only solutions I've found speak about submodules, which I'm not using, and using variations of the command: `git commit -am <dir>` or `git commit -a -m <dir>`, neither of which worked.

I don't have a .gitignore file but I was using a sparse-checkout file. I temporarily renamed that to see if it was causing the problem, despite the directory in question being listed in it, but it didn't change anything.

I'm not sure what to try next and don't understand why the changes aren't being picked up. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `git add -a` and then `git commit -am "Your Message"`

Comment: You're talking about tracked directory checked with `git ls-remote`, but `ls-remote` is about remote repository and nothing else. Can you present your folder structure and the relative position of the directory you want to add from the `.git` folder (where you run `git status`)

Comment: @Wojtek: `git add -a` returns `unkown switch`, did you mean `git -A`?

Comment: @zigam The structure is: `<dir with .git>/<subdir>/<subdir><dir_to_commit>`

Comment: @reggles10 yes i meant -A but if i try -a and -A does the same thing..

Comment: @WojtekT I did `git add -A` then `git commit -am 'message'` and it says `nothing added to the commit`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `git add <file_name>`, also what is message if you jsut try to `git commit -am "message"`

Comment: Yes, I did `git add <filename>`, I also tried `git add <dir>` as there are a load of files I'm trying to update. The message from `git commit -am "message"`: `# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#<List of files>
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)`. Just to be clear, the untracked files are not those that I'm looking to update